# Angular Pattern Directive

Tags: angular

I have a type-ahead that can only accept all numbers, or all letters. It's either a state, or zip code. So I'm trying to set the pattern directive to check if its either all letter `[a-zA-Z ]*`, or all number `[0-9]*` but not both?

What I'm trying to say is the pattern is valid if all letters, or all numbers,
but not mixed `pattern="[a-zA-Z ]* || [0-9]*`

```
<input
   pattern="[a-zA-Z ]* || [0-9]*">
   Enter State or zip
</input>

<span *ngIf='form.controls.name.errors?.pattern>
Either enter state or zip</span>
```

Comment: Are you using Reactive-Forms?

Comment: yes reactive forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change ur pattern to :

```
<input
   pattern="^[a-zA-z][\w][^0-9]*|^[0-9][\d][^a-z]">
   Enter State or zip
</input>

<span *ngIf='form.controls.name.errors?.pattern>
Either enter state or zip</span>
```